# Cross validation en R

Tags: r, validación

Queria preguntarles como hacer un método de validacion cruzada simplificado, con solo datos de entrenamiento y testeo, especificamente seleccionando 100.000 variables seleccionadas aleatoriamente como entrenamiento, y el resto para testeo e implementar la validacion cruzada 200 veces. Esto no es separando posteriormente los datos de entrenamiento, nuevamente en entrenamiento y validación?

Agradezco su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la validación cruzada, sólo se hace con el grupo de entrenamiento y no con el testeo.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(2020)
index      <- createDataPartition(datos$target, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
train<- datos[index,]         
test<- datos[-index,]
```

Con esto se logra dividir la base general en entrenamiento y testeo.

Ahora para poder realizar la validación cruzada sería de la siguiente manera:

```
fit_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 200, savePredictions = 'final', classProbs = T)
```

Con esto realizas una validación cruzada 200 veces.